# How to setup an RDC?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, remote-connection

I have 2 PCs in my home, one desktop and one laptop. Now I need to setup a remote desktop connection between them. How is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Windows has everything you need built in.  It just needs turning on.

There is a [plethora of resources on the internet](http://www.google.com/search?q=windows+7+enable+remote+desktop) that show you how to do it.

Comment: I know how to enable RDC and that windows has everything built in. But what i don't know is how to enable RDC between both the PCs. What needs to enter in "Computer" field in RDC. Is it IP address?

Comment: Either the IP address or the DNS name of the computer.

Comment: my one computer's IP address is 192.168.1.2 and other is .1.3 and they both are connected via common LAN network. But they are not being connected. plus how to find DNS?

Comment: any comments???